# C# - Save profile ASP.NET giving 'Object reference not set' error

Tags: c#, asp.net, profile

when I try to save profile, I get object reference not set to an instance of an object error.

I tried adding an 'if'
statement
    if (this.Profile.ProfileDetail != null )
But it still gave me the same error.

This is my code :

```
private void SaveProfile()
    {


            this.Profile.ProfileDetail.FullName = txtfname.Text;
            this.Profile.ProfileDetail.IdentityCardNo = txtcardno.Text;
            this.Profile.ProfileDetail.IdentityCardColour = ddlcardcolor.SelectedValue;
            this.Profile.ProfileDetail.IdentityCardExpiryDate = DateTime.Parse(txtcardexp.Text);
            this.Profile.ProfileDetail.Race = ddlrace.SelectedValue;
            this.Profile.ProfileDetail.Religion = ddlreligion.SelectedValue;
            this.Profile.ProfileDetail.ContactInformation.Address1 = txtaddress1.Text;
            this.Profile.ProfileDetail.ContactInformation.Address2 = txtaddress2.Text;
            this.Profile.ProfileDetail.ContactInformation.Address3 = txtaddress3.Text;
            this.Profile.ProfileDetail.ContactInformation.Postcode = txtpostcode.Text;
            this.Profile.ProfileDetail.ContactInformation.District = ddldistrict.SelectedValue;
            this.Profile.ProfileDetail.ContactInformation.OfficePhone = txtphoneoffice.Text;
            this.Profile.ProfileDetail.ContactInformation.HomePhone = txtphonehome.Text;
            this.Profile.ProfileDetail.ContactInformation.MobilePhone = txtphonecell.Text;
            this.Profile.ProfileDetail.ContactInformation.Email = txtemail.Text;




        //this.Profile.ProfileDetail.FirstName = txtFirstName.Text;
        //this.Profile.ProfileDetail.LastName = txtLastName.Text;
        //this.Profile.ProfileDetail.IdentityCardNo = txtICNo.Text;
        //this.Profile.ProfileDetail.DateOfBirth = DateTime.Parse(txtDateOfBirth.Text);
        //this.Profile.ProfileDetail.Gender = (Gender)Enum.Parse(typeof(Gender), ddlGender.SelectedValue, true);
        //this.Profile.Preferences.TimeZone = ddlTimeZones.SelectedValue;
        //this.Profile.Preferences.Culture = ddlCultures.SelectedValue;

        this.Profile.Save();

        this.ResetElements();
    }
```

Comment: `this.Profile` may be null, what is `this.Profile` in this case? are you logged in to application or is this property of your class? or profile of current context?

Comment: @Damith The profile is null. I clicked edit to fill the information but I am unable to save.

Comment: @Damith Thanks. It is working properly now. I added if this profile is null on top of the thingies. Thank you :'D

Answer (score 0):

The line `this.Profile.ProfileDetail` might not be the one throwing the exception. Have you stepped into the code? It probably is on the lines with the `.SelectedValue`. It will throw null if there is no value selected.

Comment: I tried commenting on the 4 lines that have 'selected value' but it still didn't work :(

Now i'm getting error at address1.text